Can a language construct like "if" be implemented as a macro in Elisp?
Open question, didn't find any answer already online or by LLM.
The result should be something like
(if (expression) (if-true) (if-false))


Of course it can; but why would you when the language already has this feature? Basically, (or (and (expression) (if-true)) (if-false)) but the proper quoting for a macro would be nontrivial.

@tripleee Hm right. I guess no language can define branching without branching already existing inside the language?

The above boolean short-circuit logic does this without explicit branching.

you can implement pretty much anything with pattern matching

Using @tripleee's suggestion: (defmacro my-if(expr if-true &rest if-false) `(or (and ,expr ,if-true) (progn ,@if-false)))

Another thread to check is the Kernel lang, or Fexpr, vau, etc. One link: https://axisofeval.blogspot.com/2011/09/kernel-underground.html
